# Unable to open include file

Tags: assembly, include, nasm, bootloader

Hello i am trying to write a assembly code in code i tried to include some another .asm code i am using nasm and code lines are

```
%include "../Desktop/Programlama/KAYRA/Asm/Boot\ Sector\ Disk/boot_sector_print.asm"
%include "../Desktop/Programlama/KAYRA/Asm/Boot\ Sector\ Disk/boot_sect_print_hex.asm"
%include "../Desktop/Programlama/KAYRA/Asm/Boot\ Sector\ Disk/boot_sector_disk.asm"
```

when i tried to complie it returnes

```
boot_sector_main.asm:22: fatal: unable to open include file `../Desktop/Programlama/KAYRA/Asm/Boot\ Sector\ Disk/boot_sector_print.asm'
```

can any one know about anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve the problem my includes are wrog i retyped like this

```
%include "boot_sector_disk.asm"
```

and problem solved